# Flashing program into microcontroller, usb-ttl, idea behind?

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, ttl, ftdi

I have limited knowledge on this topic(MCUs, communication protocols, etc.). I back then worked with an STM32 MCU and did some UART(or USART, can't remember) communication between a PC and the MCU. While I was doing that, I was using on-board ST-LINK programmer/debugger to load my programs into the MCU(F4 Discovery board, to be specific).

Now, while I was doing U(S)ART, I had to configure corresponding pins as U(S)ART alternate function along with configuring U(S)ART peripheral registers.

I recently, looking for programming so called Blue Pill board based on STM32F103Cxx MCU. The point I did not understand is, they(the tutorial owners) don't do a configuration for U(S)ART or so. Generally, they just replace a jumper from one location to another and be able to load programs via USB to TTL converters.

So, what is the exact working behind this, why don't they need to set some pins as U(S)ART Rx or Tx for example?

Another little question, I see some products sold as "FTDI programmer". Now, I do have a Prolific USB to TTL/Serial converter. Will there be a difference in functionality, can I use any USB to TTL converter for programming the MCU? I mean, does that "programmer" have a meaning, or just a naming?

Thanks.

Comment: The jumpers are putting the microcontroller into a bootloader mode when it restarts, so that those pins are then configured for USART and can be used for programming.

Comment: @RonBeyer, hmmmm, so, let's say there are 4 USART peripherals on MCU. But I can use only a specific one of them with serial programming?

Comment: In that case, yes. Two (or more) pins will be dedicated for programming when in bootloader mode.

Comment: The STM32F103 is an older chip, and apparently its bootloader only listens on UART1.  Many newer ST parts listen on a variety of interfaces and not just several UARTs but also I2C, SPI, USB, even CAN.  One of the more unfortunately aspects of the '103 is that the bootloader does not attempt to use the USB port the way many of the later ones do, to load programs to the '103 via USB you have to first put a custom bootloader in user flash by some other means.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so that's what arduino bootloader does then. There are plenty of sources which show how to load arduino bootloader into F103.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you are describing, but there's a likely case which would fit your description.

> Now, while I was doing U(S)ART, I had to configure corresponding pins as U(S)ART alternate function along with configuring U(S)ART peripheral registers.

This would be the case when the program you are writing yourself wants to do serial communication.

> I recently, looking for programming so called Blue Pill board based on STM32F103Cxx MCU. The point I did not understand is, they(the tutorial owners) don't do a configuration for U(S)ART or so. Generally, they just replace a jumper from one location to another and be able to load programs via USB to TTL converters.

This sounds like uploading new code to be received by the chip's factory ROM bootloader.   In that case, your custom code is not yet what is running on the chip, rather the factory ROM program that functions as a bootloader is.  And since that program is trying to do serial communication, ST's engineers wrote it to appropriately configure the various peripherals it is trying to use.

> Another little question, I see some products sold as "FTDI programmer". Now, I do have a Prolific USB to TTL/Serial converter. Will there be a difference in functionality, can I use any USB to TTL converter for programming the MCU? I mean, does that "programmer" have a meaning, or just a naming?

This could mean many different things, particularly with hobby/gray-market online sellers.

FTDI (as well as prolific) are IC makers, not particular ICs.  Often references to an FTDI converter would mean a part such as the FT232RL or similar, which is mostly a USB to asynchronous serial bridge with a few added capabilities.  That, or the competing chip from Prolific (or the counterfeit fake of it that you likely actually have) would be generally suitable for asynchronous serial communication with a bootloader.

But some of FTDI's other parts like the FT2232 series can also do a fairly good job of arbitrary *synchronous* serial communication, which lets them do things like implement JTAG or SWD protocols (or ATmega ISP) for more directly communicating with the chip, programming it without going through the bootloader, doing breakpoint debugging, etc.  These capabilities are necessarily chip- and brand- unique in how they function and are used by whatever PC software is operating them.  Though that PC software itself may abstract that out to a fairly similar set of user commands/operations.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer. So, when I replace that jumper into "boot mode", then in the startup, mcu will do what it is said(programmed) to do by the manufacturer which is to receive serial data from some uart peripheral of it. Correct?

Comment: Yes, in basic terms.  The exact behavior of the bootloader would be specified in the documentation somewhere, in some cases it may contain bail-out conditions or there may be a command which can be used to startup user code.

Answer (score 2):

How to program the part, what is available is all documented in the ST documentation, between the datasheet and the reference manual.

The boot0 pin (datasheet usually) as shown in the documentation (reference manual usually) shows what the boot paths are when reset or powered on with the boot pin in that state.  Other than the latest wave of products from them that meant it boots from your code (application flash) or from the bootloader.  You can do an sram thing too but dont worry about that all you need to do is read the docs and this is clear.

That part has a bootloader that can be programmed using uart or probably i2c maybe spi (but NOT usb).

When designing a product around one of these microcontrollers you have to decide how you want to program it.  pre-program it and provide no field programmability, use pads/jumpers/headers to use one of the programming methods provided by the part, or make a bootloader where you choose the path (none of the above as you are in your bootloader not theirs so you create the protocol, etc).

There are also the swdio and swclk pins (datasheet) that provide access to the arm core, the arm core then can be halted and through that swd interface (jtag like, but not jtag) you can access the arm bus and if/since the arm bus can talk to the st logic and program the flash then through that path you can program the flash if you have the right software.  openocd happens to know how to handle that part (flash programming these days is part specific not generic so requires code for each one or you download your code to ram and then that code programs the flash).

So when you hook up an stlink or jlink or other debugger to the bottom end of that board you are coming in through that swd interface.  So long as you have not hung the arm core, you can go through it to get at the flash, ram, peripherals, etc.  If you have hung it you have the boot0 pin you can use to boot into the debugged bootloader from which you can then halt that through the debugger and then program the application flash or load a program in ram or whatever.

stlink, jlink, are just interface boards, they need software that can speak their langauge to then ask them to perform the swd protocol commands for you.  openocd and others also support ftdi parts with mpsse which is a tiny state machine language if you will to tell the part to wiggle pins for you in a timed manner.  ft2232, ft4232 and a number of others but not all.  FTDI is well known for usb to something parts, and the 2232 and parts like it support uart out of the gate but also have big bang modes and mpsse mode and in that mode you can do i2c, spi, jtag, swd, and whatever other protocol you wish within the pins available.  So a simple ftdi breakout board will work just fine for doing swd.  Get one with two or more ports exposed and you can do both swd and uart and not need two boards.

When you buy a nucleo board it has another mcu on it a debugger, which also supports the stlink protocol which is a usb protocol from st, but it is just an interface, openocd can be used with stlink to program nxp or atmel or other parts with cortex-m cores in it not just ones from st, but the onboard debugger is wired to the target mcu such that it can reprogram that mcu.  That debugger end also on some of the boards provides a virtual com port connected to the target uart, so that you can through usb get uart/serial access to the target mcu without having to buy extra hardware.  Also that debugger creates a virtual thumb drive, you drag and drop your .bin file (arm-whatever-objdump -O binary hello.elf hello.bin) and the debugger mcu will take that file and program it into the target mcu's flash and reset the target mcu.

The blue pill though was very popular and still is for the arduino world trying to get a non-avr with some horsepower.  A fair amount of work was put into that including a usb based bootloader that speaks a protocol that arduino (the tools) supports (meaning someone created a protocol and added arduino support and a bootloader).  If either through that protocol or through one of the other entry points you overwrite that bootloader (trivial to do) then you use that usb programming capability and have to use one of the other paths to put that bootloader back on. So this is a case of a roll your own bootloader that didnt come from ST.  Because the blue pill has been so massively cloned there is no reason to assume that any one you buy will come preprogrammed with it.

For about $5 you can get a not really a jlink board, little purple thing, look for stm32 jlink even though it has no affiliation with either (well it may speak the jlink usb protocol sure).  For about $10 you get into the nucleo cards which the wider ones the debugger end is physically removable but you dont have to do that remove two jumpers and use four wires and you can use that front end with openocd or whatever to program most anything cortex-m based.  Many if not all of the (real) discovery boards can do that too.  If you are tired of getting ripped off on ebay you can sometimes find the $5 jlink board on amazon or other for a bit more.  You can also find an ftdi breakout board on adafruit, I am looking at one right now ft232h.  note that not all ft232 parts will work, you have to confirm it by doing a little research.  The adafruit board is single ported and/or only has one port exposed so either swd or uart but not both at the same time.  For under $10 you can get a raspberry pi usb serial cable with four dangling female headers on the other end (has an ftdi part in it) and you can use it along with boot0 and some software (protocol is simple can bang out your own tool in one sitting) to use the uart interface (can do this with the ftdi board as well).

The newer stm32 parts (stm32g030 for example).  If the application flash is erased then it will run the bootloader that supports uart, otherwise by default that is considered a security risk and wont.  You can use that one shot to load a program that clears the security bits (non-volatile) and you can then use boot0 and the uart programming interface to your hearts content, otherwise swd is your path in, and thats it.  Some part vendors swd is the only path.  atmel (now microchip) used to have this sam-ba bootloader much like sts just different uart protocol (also pretty simple) but it is no longer embedded, they will give you source to it and you can put it on the flash yourself, but why bother it is way more bloated than something you could do yourself and their flash locking leaves a lot to be desired.  I suspect st is going to go that way and not have the bootloader after a while.  Some cortex-m vendors are swd only, that is all you get (and if you hang the arm you may have to remove the part and put another one down, so be careful)

Anyway 100% of this is documented, some in sts docs some in the blue pill main or fan pages, arms documentation, etc.  But primarily the boot0/1 pins are documented by st as to what they do.  There is documentation for the uart interface, note that over time the bootloader changed and not every part uses the same features, some require a page of this size or require (only support) the enhanced write over the regular write, etc.  But the protocol itself will tell you what commands it supports.  Again first time at it its an afternoon to write your own (may take you just as long to try to get someone elses tool to work) software to talk to the bootloader and program the flash.  Some blue pills arrived locked and I had to use the uart bootloader to unlock.  Later I think I figured out how to unlock them using openocd/swd.  Once unlocked then it is unlocked and wasnt going to buy dozens of these to prove the theories.

Comment: Well, thanks for such an answer. Although it is way beyond my level right now, I hope I will revise it later.

Comment: Yep, understood.  get the st docs (datasheet and reference manual) look for boot0 or boot see what you find, go from there.

Comment: I am aware both documents, i will look them for boot sections as you said. I also might need to look for bootloader concept in general. Thanks again.

Comment: nothing magic, the term is generically used but ideally it means it boots the part (first code that runs) and has load capabilities (sometimes the term is used without this) so it can be used to load other code into the part in a way it can be run.  so in this case it can boot the part and like the usb one that you use with arduino, it can load a program into a portion of flash so that you can boot the part and run your program.